# MySQL GROUP BY return the first item - Need to select the last item

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has duplicate data for the same user_id. I need to select the newest record for each user_id. When i use group by then order. mysql does the function in that order and i get the wrong records.

Table - `tblUsersProfile`

Field           Type    Null    Default Comments
id          int(11) No  AI
user_id         int(7)  No
first_name_id   int(11) No
last_name_id    int(11) No
location_id int(11) No
dob         date    Yes     NULL
sex         int(1)  Yes     NULL    1 for Male, 0 for Female 
created_by  int(21) No
activity_ts timestamp   No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.* from tblUsersProfile as t1
inner join (
select user_id,max(activity_ts) as rct
from tblUsersProfile
group by user_id) as t2
on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.activity_ts = t2.rct
```

Maybe my query is even more "complicated" than necessary if you have all the others data redundants and equals for all records.